# Changing colours of text, cells and view controllers across the whole app using a switch

Tags: ios, swift, view, uicolor, uiswitch

I am trying to integrate a night mode into my app and have partially got it working, Here is my code and a screenshot of how the app changes when the night mode switch is used.  The settings screen is perfect but the first two view controllers aren't changing colour as expected for an all black background.

```
import UIKit

var selectedRunesArray = runesIncReversedArray

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var allowReversedRunesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var allowDuplicateRunesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nightModeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var allowReversedRunesSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var allowDuplicateRunesSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var nightModeSwitch: UISwitch!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let revRunes = defaults.value(forKey: "reversedRunes") {
            allowReversedRunesSwitch.isOn = revRunes as! Bool
        }

        if let dupRunes = defaults.value(forKey: "duplicateRunes") {
            allowDuplicateRunesSwitch.isOn = dupRunes as! Bool
        }

        if let nMode = defaults.value(forKey: "nightMode") {
            nightModeSwitch.isOn = nMode as! Bool
        }

    }

    @IBAction func reversedRunesChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "reversedRunes")

        if allowReversedRunesSwitch.isOn == true {

            selectedRunesArray = runesIncReversedArray

        } else {
            selectedRunesArray = runesArray
        }

    }

    @IBAction func duplicateRunesChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "duplicateRunes")

        if allowDuplicateRunesSwitch.isOn == true {



        } else {



        }

    }

    @IBAction func nightModeChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "nightMode")

        if nightModeSwitch.isOn == true {

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black 
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            allowReversedRunesLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            allowDuplicateRunesLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            nightModeLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)

        } else {

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
            allowReversedRunesLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            allowDuplicateRunesLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            nightModeLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground

        }

    }

}
```

[image: App before and after night mode switch is toggled]

Comment: First, use `defaults.bool(forKey:)` instead of risky force down casting.  Second, where is the code in your first two view controllers that reacts to the dark setting?

Comment: Hi Paul, the code I have in the Settings View Controller is all I have as I don't know how to manipulate the others in the other two view controllers unfortunately

Comment: You will need some similar code, probably in `viewWillAppear` that checks the value from user defaults and sets the colour of your ui items as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the change to happen globally, I would recommend the following approach:

```
// an extension here is helpful
extension Notification.Name {

    static let dayOrNight = Notification.Name(rawValue: "dayOrNight")

}


// add the switch and set its state from the current user default
func addNightModeSwitch() {

    toggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nightModeSwitchAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "nightMode") {
        toggle.isOn = true
    } else {
        toggle.isOn = false
    }

    ...

}


// post a notification when the switch is switched
@objc func nightModeSwitchAction(_ toggle: UISwitch) {

    if toggle.isOn {

        // update user default
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "nightMode")

        // post notification
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dayOrNight, object: nil)

    } else {

        // update user default
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "nightMode")

        // post notification
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dayOrNight, object: nil)

    }

}


// add a notification observer to any view controller where you want UI changes
func addNotificationObservers() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dayOrNightHandler), name: .dayOrNight, object: nil)

}


// make sure all of the objects that need changes are instance properties of the view controller and change them through the notification observer's action
@objc func dayOrNightHandler() {

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    someButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    ...

}
```

And in the view controller where the actual switch is located, you can animate the changes in the notification observer's action method which I think is a nice touch (i.e. Twitter).